# How to avoid public key spoofing?

Tags: vb.net, encryption, licensing, drm

I am doing an activation server which will enable users to activate their software. The problem is that they own the public key.. the verification method needs the public key to check signature of the license file. My concern is that someone could generate their own license file using two key (public and private) and then change the public key on the client which would spoof his current license.

Is there any way of avoiding this ? Where should the public key be stored ? You have to take into consideration that the checkup is done on client and the signature is created on server.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use a licensing file.  Each time the application is started, have it connect to a licensing server to validate it.

Comment: Wireshark, DNS-Spoof/Redirector, localhost, 127.0.0.1. Emulator. Done!

Answer (score 0):

So? The whole point of a public key encryption that the decryption can only be done by the key's counterpart. If you app encrypts something with the user's public key and sends it to your server, they can't decrypt that data packet, because only the private key you possess will work.

If the user's license file is encrypted with your private key, only their public key can decrypt it. This way, even if the license file gets shared, you'd be able to track down who shared it because only one user's key would've been able to decrypt it.

Comment: I believe the OP is asking how to prevent the user from replacing the public key in the application (activation client); if the public key was replaced the user could spoof the activation server using their own public/private pair

Comment: At some point it becomes pointless to worry about activation bypasses. If the user is good enough to swap out keys, then they can probably disable the entire activation system anyways.

Comment: @Marc B not bad you probably right.. but still maybe someone have an hint about this. I believe this havent answered the question.